# Python 'cannot import name 'TestCase'' When importing unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

Whenever I attempt:

```
import unittest
```

I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wackyTesting.py", line 1, in <module>
    import unittest
  File "C:\.....\Python\Python36\lib\unittest\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from .case import (TestCase, FunctionTestCase, SkipTest, skip, skipIf,
ImportError: cannot import name 'TestCase'
```

This happens regardless of where the code is run, there is nothing in the root that could be causing a conflict. I have tried re-installing unittest but it didn't help. It was working perfectly until just recently. Any ideas?

Comment: do you have a file named `unittest.py` or `unittest.pyc`?

Comment: @MooingRawr Nope, I've seen that other people have had similar issues because of that but i don't have anything like that.

Comment: What happens if you `import unittest` inside a virtual environment using python3.6? If you've never used virtualenv, you can ignore this comment.

Comment: @MooingRawr: The error message clearly shows it's finding `__init__.py` in the Python Lib\unittest folder, so it's not a *this file doesn't exist* error. If you inspect that directory, there is a `__init__.py` file in it, and it contains a `from .case import (TestCase...` statement.

Comment: @byxor I installed it and followed the documentation. I got the same error when i ran it from the virtual environment. (Assuming i set it up correctly.)

Comment: Do you have any other versions of python (before 3.6) that you could try?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I just uninstalled python completely and reinstalled. Nothing quite like turning it off and on again. That seems to have done it, maybe there's a more elegant solution but this will have to do for now.

Comment: Seems like the best solution to me. Although be careful uninstalling python (especially python2) on some linux distributions (like Ubuntu). It has a high risk of breaking your entire OS.